# How to downgrade/upgrade plan in Stripe payments using API in PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have already subscribed to a plan. Now I want to downgrade it. So should I unsubscribe the current plan? What will be the process of refunding the remaining amount?

I have created customer and subscribed customer to plan while creating customer. I have not used Charge class. To refund amount do we need charge_id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have already subscribed to a plan. Now I want to downgrade it.  What will be the process of refunding the remaining amount?

From [the API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription):

> `POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/{CUSTOMER_ID}/subscription`
>
> Subscribes a customer to a plan, meaning the customer will be billed monthly starting from signup. If the customer already has an active subscription, we'll update it to the new plan and optionally prorate the price we charge next month to make up for any price changes.

It's pretty clear that this is what you want to do.

> To refund amount do we need charge_id?

While you probably don't need to refund it yourself, given the way that changing the subscription works, the [docs on refunding](https://stripe.com/docs/api#refund_charge) say that you do need the charge ID.

Given that the answers to your questions were entirely contained within the documentation, I highly advise you to review the documentation before asking your next question.

Comment: yeah I was going through the documentation, found this link which is very useful, thanks for response
https://answers.stripe.com/questions/can-i-invoice-and-charge-for-prorated-upgrades-downgrades-immediately